# Table-driven test always shows parent as failing when using testify

Tags: go, testing, testify

When using [testify](https://github.com/stretchr/testify/assert) with table-driven tests as in:

```golang
func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    a := assert.New(t)
    tc := []struct {
        desc string
        foo  string
    }{
        {
            desc: "fail abc",
            foo:  "abc",
        },
        {
            desc: "fail def",
            foo:  "def",
        },
    }
    for _, tC := range tc {
        t.Run(tC.desc, func(t *testing.T) {
            tC := tC
            a.Equal(tC.foo, "ghi")
        })
    }
}
```

Your failures will come back ambiguous:

```
--- FAIL: TestFoo (0.00s)
    /test.go:27: 
            Error Trace:    /test.go:27
            Error:          Not equal: 
                            expected: "abc"
                            actual  : "ghi"
                            
                            Diff:
                            --- Expected
                            +++ Actual
                            @@ -1 +1 @@
                            -abc
                            +ghi
            Test:           TestFoo
    /test.go:27: 
            Error Trace:    /test.go:27
            Error:          Not equal: 
                            expected: "def"
                            actual  : "ghi"
                            
                            Diff:
                            --- Expected
                            +++ Actual
                            @@ -1 +1 @@
                            -def
                            +ghi
            Test:           TestFoo
FAIL
```

Rather than telling you which subtest failed, they all show the parent test having failed (e.g. `TestFoo` instead of `TestFoo/fail_abc`). If there are many tests in the table, this can make the test completely useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When initializing the testify shorthand, it must use the `*testing.T` from the sub-test. If you have the same habit as me of putting `a := assert.New(t)` at the top of every test, you'll end up passing `*testing.T` from the parent, so the failures will always show as coming from the parent.

Rewriting as

```golang
func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    tc := []struct {
        desc string
        foo  string
    }{
        {
            desc: "fail abc",
            foo:  "abc",
        },
        {
            desc: "fail def",
            foo:  "def",
        },
    }
    for _, tC := range tc {
        t.Run(tC.desc, func(t *testing.T) {
            tC := tC
            a := assert.New(t) // Now using *testing.T from within the sub-test
            a.Equal(tC.foo, "ghi")
        })
    }
}
```

Gets the expected legible output (i.e. failures broken up by sub-test and test names including the description):

```
--- FAIL: TestFoo (0.00s)
    --- FAIL: TestFoo/fail_abc (0.00s)
        boop_test.go:27: 
                Error Trace:    /test.go:27
                Error:          Not equal: 
                                expected: "abc"
                                actual  : "ghi"
                            
                                Diff:
                                --- Expected
                                +++ Actual
                                @@ -1 +1 @@
                                -abc
                                +ghi
                Test:           TestFoo/fail_abc
    --- FAIL: TestFoo/fail_def (0.00s)
        boop_test.go:27: 
                Error Trace:    /test.go:27
                Error:          Not equal: 
                                expected: "def"
                                actual  : "ghi"
                            
                                Diff:
                                --- Expected
                                +++ Actual
                                @@ -1 +1 @@
                                -def
                                +ghi
                Test:           TestFoo/fail_def
FAIL
```